# How to add padding zeros with hyphen and max number length is 10 in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Add padding zeros with hyphen and max number length is 10 in ES6

```
1234 = 12000000-34
12134 = 12100000-34
121234 = 12120000-34
1212334 = 12123000-34
12123434 = 12123400-34
121234534 = 12123450-34
1212345634 = 12123456-34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method

```js
function format(num) {
  return (num.slice(0, -2) + '00000000').slice(0, 8) + '-' + (num.slice(-2) + '00').slice(0, 2)
}

console.log(format(''));
console.log(format('1'));
console.log(format('12'));
console.log(format('123'));
console.log(format('1234'));
console.log(format('12134'));
console.log(format('121234'));
console.log(format('1212334'));
console.log(format('12123434'));
console.log(format('121234534'));
console.log(format('1212345634'));
```

Comment: I'm try to change format like below , my logic is not workout, can you help on this?  1234 = 12000034-00
12134 = 12000134-00
121234 = 12001234-00
1212334 = 12012334-00
12123434 = 12123434-00
121234534 = 12123453-40
1212345634 = 12123456-34

Comment: @Karthik :  for that little more complex logic is needed